# JQuery validation plugin: Custom messages for custom validation methods

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I created this custom method for managing regular expressions:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    },
    "Text not valid"
```

);

And then I used my method:

```
$(function() {
  $("#registerform").validate({
    rules: { password: {required: true, regex: "^[a-zA-Z09]+$"} },
    messages: {
    password: {regex: "A password can contain only letters or digits"}
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is that, while I can overwrite the default message for standard validation methods (like required) inside the call to validate(), I can't do it for custom methods. So, my page will display "Text not valid" instead of "A password can contain only letters or digits". How can I do to provide a default message and to allow to overwrite it??

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking.  Why can't you just leave the message _"text not valid"_ out of your custom method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave the message out of your custom method if you want to always set a custom message within your `.validate()` options.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    }
);
```

> How can I do to provide a default message and to allow to overwrite
>   it?

I don't believe this is possible.  After all, it's reasonable to assume that since one is already using their own custom method, why would they also want to over-ride it.

Your only option would be to use a message inside the custom method or set the message within your `.validate()` options, but not both.